# unmanaged struct to managed marshaling

Tags: .net, c++-cli, interop

I would like to marshal ums to s (which are of similarly aligned types):

```
void F(ManagedStruct ^s)
{
  ummanagedStruct ums;
  FillTheStruct(&ums);
  s = ?
}
```

Do I need to allocate unmanaged memory using AllocHGlobal like so?:

```
void F(ManagedStruct ^s)
{
  IntPtr ptr = Marshal::AllocHGlobal(Marshal::SizeOf(s);

  FillTheStruct(static_cast<unmanagedStruct*>(ptr.ToPointer);
  s = (ManagedStruct^)Marshal::PtrToStruct(ptr, ManagedStruct::typeid);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   void F(ManagedStruct ^s)
```

That's wrong if you intended to pass the value back to the caller.  The argument must be passed by reference so the caller's variable can be updated.  The ^ hat is wrong as well if "ManagedStruct" is in fact a value type.  You only use it on reference types, the kind you declare with `ref struct` or `ref class`.  Sadly the C++/CLI doesn't generate a diagnostic for such usage, it assumes you intentionally meant to box the value.

Fix:

```
  void F(ManagedStruct% s)
```

or the generally saner one for value types:

```
  ManagedStruct F() {
      unmanagedStruct ums;
      FillTheStruct(&ums);
      return (ManagedStruct)Marshal::PtrToStructure(IntPtr(&ums), ManagedStruct::typeid);
  }
```

With the note that Marshal::PtrToStructure() is convenient but it is neither safer nor faster than the alternative, simply copying the structure members one by one.